# Vertical lines for data points in geom_point() in ggplot2 for R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to get vertical lines as the data point representations in `ggplot2`?  None of the shape options 0-25 are what I'm looking for, so I'm guessing I need another add-in or a way to change the dimensions of shape 15.  [The left chart here](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2020/08/21/a-world-full-of-viruses) is an example of what I want it to look like.

Here's some simple code in case it's helpful in writing the response:

```
a <- c(1, 3, 5)
b <- c(2, 4, 6)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
geom_point(shape = 15)
```

Comment: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point(pch = "|", cex = 7)`

Comment: you could also use ggplots very own arguments, shape and size. `geom_point(shape = "|", size = 7)`, is identical

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two possible methods to help produce a vertical glyph similar to what you see in the referenced plot.

The first is a workaround and makes use of the `geom_errorbar()` function. The second involves passing specific numeric values to the `shape` parameter, but with the help of the `scale_shape_identity()` function.

```
# Reproducing your data

a <- c(1, 3, 5)
b <- c(2, 4, 6)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

# Let's specify the upper and lower limits manually

df <- df |>
  mutate(
    upper = +0.5 + b,
    lower = -0.5 + b
  )
```

The first approach exploits the `geom_errorbar()` function, except we set `width = 0` to suppress the horizontal lines. Note, I set the upper and lower limits manually and appended them to your data frame. Adjust the vertical distances to suit your needs.

```
# 1st Method

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), color = "red", width = 0) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: error bar workaround]

The second approach exploits the `shape` parameter directly. Note, the `geom_point()` function’s `shape` parameter accommodates a variety of different values. Shape values from 0 to 25 are commonly used, but others exist. In particular, shapes 32 to 127 correspond to various ASCII characters. Layer on `scale_shape_identity()` and you may pass through any legal shape value. The value 73 or 108 should work well.

To offer further insight, the numeric values we pass to the `shape` parameter are also referred to as ASCII codes. In particular, code 73 corresponds to the uppercase letter "I" (i.e., `"I"`) and code 108 corresponds to the lowercase letter "l" (i.e., `"l"`). In your plot the letters will appear without the serifs (i.e., crossbars), transforming all your points into vertical bars. See below for a demonstration:

```
# 2nd Method

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b)) + 
  scale_shape_identity() +
  geom_point(shape = 108, size = 10, color = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: shape value 108]

In fact, passing in any of the following characters will produce a vertical line: `"|"`, `"l"`, or `"I"`.

```
# Other possible solutions

geom_point(shape = "I")  # ASCII code 73
geom_point(shape = "l")  # ASCII code 108
geom_point(shape = "|")  # ASCII code 124
```

Comment: really no need to use different arguments than shape and size. `geom_point(pch = "|", cex = 7)` and  `geom_point(shape = "|", size = 7)`, are identical

Comment: I'd probably favour another option - use of geom_segment.

Comment: @tjebo You're correct, thank you. The following may be passed to *either* the `shape` parameter or the `pch` parameter: `"|"`, `"l"`, or `"I"`. The third example is redundant so I edited my response.